# Running a Node.js Angular.js Gulp.js application forever

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am working on a Angular.js and Gulp.js web application and want to run it in a Ubuntu 12.04 environment permanently. I installed the Angular & Bootstrap 4 dashboard boiler in this environment. It comes with Gulp as a build tool. Now I want to run this application permanently in order to make it accessible to customers / website visitors. I read about Gulp Forever and Gulp Forever Monitor and I installed the modules, but they didn´t do the trick. The application always shuts down after a while and I have to restart it in the environment via Terminal.

So, what would be the best way to run a Gulp application forever? How can I do that, what do I need to install? As I am new to this, any hints and recommendations would be appreciated, thanks!

Here´s the gulpfile.js, which contains the gulp serve task:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrench = require('wrench');
var forever = require('gulp-forever-monitor');

wrench.readdirSyncRecursive('./gulp').filter(function(file) {
  return (/\.(js)$/i).test(file);
}).map(function(file) {
  require('./gulp/' + file);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], function () {
  gulp.start('build');
});
/*
gulp.task('run:server', function() {
    var foreverMonitorOptions = {
        env: process.env,
        args: process.argv,
        watch: true, // can pass if you set any watch option, for example watchIgnorePatterns
        watchIgnorePatterns:  ['.*', 'node_modules/**', 'public/**', 'temp/**']
    }

    forever('gulpfile.js', foreverMonitorOptions)
        .on('watch:restart', function(fileInfo) {
            console.log('server was restarted');
        })
        .on('exit', function() {
            console.log('server was closed');
        })
    gulp.start('build');
})
*/
```

Comment: Gulp is essentially a build tool. If you want to run your application for testing use something like [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using plain [Forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever). It can be used to keep any script running from the command line.

Comment: Ok, thanks so far - I already knew Forever. The problem that I´m having with this application is, that when I install Forever via NPM, I don´t know how to run this through the Terminal. Whenever I installed Forever and started the application with "forever gulp serve", I got error messages. Am I missing out on something here?

Comment: What is your gulp serve command doing? If it is just starting a web server then you may be better off with a tool besides Gulp.

Comment: I added the Gulpfile.js to the question, with the Gulp tasks.

Comment: Could you provide the error messages from "forever gulp serve"? Were they from gulp or forever?